# Different result in ContourPlot function using different version of Mathematica (?)

Tags: plotting, scoping, version-11, version-6

I tested "[Elasticity with Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=7065)" notebook (Mathematica 6) in Mathematica 11.3 and tested  [C05_stress_kirsch.nb](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1abEWbWQrRah3yw8m-IQOPRqoNw1V8vWW?usp=sharing), I added some trigger code to protected function in the tensor2analysis.m file, and then ran C05_stress_kirsch.nb. All of the output match with the original file, but it gave different result in either ContourPlot or Show function.

here is the sample that has different output code (link above to see full codes) :

```
SS = Stress /. myrule /. numrule;
SC = StressCart /. numrule;
d = 3;
g1 = ContourPlot[N[SC[[1, 1]]], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, Contours -> 50, Compiled -> True, 
   ContourShading -> True, ContourLines -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[2/3 (1 - #)] &), DisplayFunction -> Identity];
g2 = Show[
   Graphics[{GrayLevel[1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
     Axes -> Automatic], DisplayFunction -> Identity];
Show[{g1, g2}, DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction
```

]

here is the desired result :

[image]

and here is mine :

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're referring to the white lobes around the disk in the bottom picture? My guess would be that the two version have different automatic plot ranges. You could try playing around with the option `PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {zmin, zmax}}`. It looks to me like part of the red region is getting cut off as it's either greater than zmax or less than zmin. Try changing zmin and zmax and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the option `ClippingStyle` with `ContourPlot`, for example

```
ClippingStyle->Automatic
```

[image]